# Prevent urxvt hollow cursor

Tags: urxvt

Using urxvt if I accidentally tap my clickpad while urxvt is in focus, the cursor goes "hollow". Toggling focus will bring it back to normal. How can I prevent if from going hollow in the first place?

**Update**

It seems to be related to running urxvt "full-screen".

Comment: What window manager are you using?

Comment: At the time I was having this problem, I was using goomwwm. I've since changed WM and I no longer see this issue. It was definitely related to running urxvt full-screen.